# Cisco 1841 stuck on boot?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

I found an old Cisco 1841 router and decided to boot it up to play with it a little. Everything seemed to be going ok but I guess something interrupted the boot.
Last line is
`%SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 10.60.60.11 started - reconnectio`
After this it just starts sending random characters over serial. What can I do to solve this?
Here's the entire log from the console:

```
System Bootstrap, Version 12.3(8r)T9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2004 by cisco Systems, Inc.
PLD version 0x10
GIO ASIC version 0x127
c1841 processor with 262144 Kbytes of main memory
Main memory is configured to 64 bit mode with parity disabled


Readonly ROMMON initialized
program load complete, entry point: 0x8000f000, size: 0xc100

Initializing ATA monitor library.......
program load complete, entry point: 0x8000f000, size: 0xc100

Initializing ATA monitor library.......

˙÷˙˙program load complete, entry point: 0x8000f000, size: 0x10f80d4
Self decompressing the image : #############################################################################################################˙#####################################˙############################ [OK]

Smart Init is enabled
smart init is sizing iomem
  ID            MEMORY_REQ         TYPE
                0X003AA110 public buffer pools
                0X00211000 public particle pools
                0X00020000 Crypto module pools
                0X000021B8 Onboard USB

If any of the above Memory Requirements are
"UNKNOWN", you may be using an unsupported
configuration or there is a software problem and
system operation may be compromised.

Allocating additional 19653665 bytes to IO Memory.
PMem allocated: 240123904 bytes; IOMem allocated: 28311552 bytes
˙
              Restricted Rights Legend

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is
subject to restrictions as set forth in subparagraph
(c) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted
Rights clause at FAR sec. 52.227-19 and subparagraph
(c) (1) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer
Software clause at DFARS sec. 252.227-7013.

           cisco Systems, Inc.
           170 West Tasman Drive
           San Jose, California 95134-1706



Cisco IOS Software, 1841 Software (C1841-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 12.4(3g), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2006 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 06-Nov-06 01:09 by alnguyen
Image text-base: 0x600886DC, data-base: 0x61A80000

żPort Statistics for unclassified packets is not turned on.

This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco 1841 (revision 6.0) with 234496K/27648K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FCZ104720KR
2 FastEthernet interfaces
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity disabled.
191K bytes of NVRAM.
62720K bytes of ATA CompactFlash (Read/Write)


If the interface doesn't support baby giant frames
maximum mtu of the interface has to be reduced by 4
bytes on both sides of the connection to properly
transmit or receive large packets. Please refer to
documentation on configuring IEEE 802.1Q vLANs.



Press RETURN to get started!

sslinit fn

*Jul 16 09:57:56.559: %VPN_HW-6-INFO_LOC: Crypto engine: onboard 0  State changed to: Initialized
*Jul 16 09:57:56.563: %VPN_HW-6-INFO_LOC: Crypto engine: onboard 0  State changed to: Enabled
*Jul 16 2019 10:57:59.267: %SYS-6-CLOCKUPDATE: System clock has been updated from 09:57:59 UTC Tue Jul 16 2019 to 10:57:59 CET Tue Jul 16 2019, configured from console by console.
*Jul 16 2019 11:57:59.271: %SYS-6-CLOCKUPDATE: System clock has been updated from 10:57:59 CET Tue Jul 16 2019 to 11:57:59 CET-SUM Tue Jul 16 2019, configured from console by console.
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:00.731: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from memory by console
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:00.919: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to up
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:00.919: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to up
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:01.423: %SYS-5-RESTART: System restarted --
Cisco IOS Software, 1841 Software (C1841-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 12.4(3g), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2006 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 06-Nov-06 01:09 by alnguyen
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:01.427: %SNMP-5-COLDSTART: SNMP agent on host hzzo_ri01-c1841 is undergoing a cold start
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:01.443: %SSH-5-ENABLED: SSH 1.99 has been enabled
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:01.739: %CRYPTO-6-ISAKMP_ON_OFF: ISAKMP is OFF
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:01.939: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to up
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:01.939: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to up
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:02.871: %SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 10.60.60.11 started - CLI initiated
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:03.991: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to down
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:04.047: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to down
*Jul 16 2019 11:58:09.991: %SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 10.60.60.11 started - reconnectio˙˙űý˙˙˙˙˙÷˙ű˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙ű˙ű˙˙˙˙˙űű˙˙˙˙ďď˙˙˙
```

Comment: I would recommend to restart this router with 0x2142 and clear the configuration. You can find a lot of URL how do this in the Internet. For example this one
https://www.sunsetlearning.com/password-recovery-for-cisco-routers/

Comment: This looks like a configuration where the console speed setting between ROMMON and IOS is different.

Comment: Okay so tried to restart this router with 0x2142 but I ran into another issue...I can't type anything into the console over serial port. Could this be the issue with the serial port to USB adapter?

Comment: Issue was in the cable...Got a new one and everything works fine :)